# How to get an element in a View from a Controller?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch 2,0,1.

I need to get an element from a View in a Controller.

At the moment I use this method, which get the View correctly, but I am not able to get the Item in the View. I do not get any error just test is undefined.

Any ideas?

In the Controller:

```
var test = this.getDetailView().items['editButton'];
```

Code in the View:

```
Ext.define('XXX.view.DetailView',{
   ...

   items: [

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Edit XXX',
            ui: 'custom-btn-dwn-timetable',
            itemId: 'editButton'
        }
  ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) in this case to get your button:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#editButton')[1];
```

Comment: thanks it works, may I ask you how to hide the selected element? thanks

Comment: I think you just need to use [hide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-hide) method

Comment: This didn't work for me, it couldn't find the itemId

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple other ways to get the reference to the edit button. You can wire the edit button as a **ref** like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            editButton: '#editButton'
        }
    },
```

Then in your controller you can call the automatically generated getter`this.getEditButton()` to get the actual edit button component.

Another thing you can do is save the edit button as an instance variable on your view like this:

```
Ext.define('XXX.view.DetailView',{
   ...

   items: [

        this.editButton = Ext.widget{(
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Edit XXX',
            ui: 'custom-btn-dwn-timetable',
            itemId: 'editButton'
        )}
  ],
    ...
}
```

So now to access your button in the controller you have to do: `this.getDetailView().editButton`

In general, if an element is something you access a lot you should have a saved reference to it, rather than querying the DOM (to avoid unnecessary performance hit). Using Ext.getCmp() is also slower due to execution stack (it has to go through the ComponentManager every single time just to get the reference).

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting your button id to `edit` and then

```
Ext.getCmp('edit').hide();
```